# Piped greps for looking inside files

Tags: command-line, grep, find, pipe

*(self-migrated from ask-ubuntu because it's linux-related, not ubuntu, and my os isn't ubuntu)*

I'm trying to make a grep that looks like this:

```
grep -r 2019 | grep -riv FAILED | grep -rl DSL
```

I want to get filenames (`-l`) of files containing `2019` in them, AND NOT (`-v`) containing `FAILED` AND containing `DSL`.

Here, only the last grep is executed. I understand it's because of the `-r`, so each grep greps on all files instead of the previous result. But I can't figure out how to make it work without `-r`.

Maybe there's another way to use multiple patterns on a grep but with "positive" and "negative" match I haven't found anything.

Comment: (a) You can ask [text-processing questions on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tags/text-processing) if you're using Ubuntu, and (b) this is not a migrated post, this is manually cross-posted (which is not allowed here). To migrate [your post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1160461) from Ask Ubuntu to here, flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @muru Yeah I wasn't sure how to do that but I realized I had no reason to post it on Ubuntu as my os isn't even an ubuntu. Should I delete my other post?

Comment: You should, but you can't, since it has an upvoted answer. Flag it for moderator attention, and ask it to be migrated here, instead.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-r` from the 2nd and 3rd `grep`?

Comment: Are you trying to process files content, or file-names? You question is not clear on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last `grep` in the pipeline would be reading from the previous `grep` (if it hadn't used the `-r` option, see later), so it would have no idea from what *file* the data came from, which in turn means it can't report the pathname of the file.

Instead, consider using `find` like so:

```
find . -type f \
    -exec grep -q 2019 {} \; \
    -exec grep -q DSL {} \; \
    ! -exec grep -qi FAILED {} \; \
    -print
```

This would take each regular file from the current directory and any subdirectory (recursively) and test whether it contains the strings `2019`, `DSL`, and `FAILED` (case insensitively).  It would print the pathnames of file that contain the first two string but that does not contain the third.

If a file does not contain `2019` the other two tests will not be carried out, and if it does not contain `DSL`, the last test will ont be carried out, etc.

Note that instead of `grep -v -qi FAILED` I'm using a negation of `grep -qi FAILED` as the third test.  I'm not interested in whether the file contains lines not containing `FAILED`, I'm interested in whether the file *contains* `FAILED`, and in that case I'd like to skip this file.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

The issue with your pipeline,

```
grep -r 2019 | grep -riv FAILED | grep -rl DSL
```

is that the last `grep` will look recursively in all the files in the current directory and below and will ignore the input from the previous stages of the pipeline.  The two initial `grep` invocations may produce some data, but they would fail to forward this through the pipeline and will eventually be killed when the last `grep` is done.

Also, as I already noted above, the middle `grep` would not find files that does not contain `FAILED`, it would find files that contain lines with things other than `FAILED`.  Incidentally, it would *also* ignore the input from the preceding `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep` (`-r` is already a GNU extension) and GNU `xargs` or compatible:

```
grep -rlZ 2019 . |
  xargs -r0 grep -LiZ FAILED |
  xargs -r0 grep -l DSL
```

You need `xargs` to be able to pass the list of files *output* by one `grep` as *arguments* to the next `grep`. And `-Z` for that list of files to be NUL-delimited. To report the list of files that don't contain FAILED, it's `-L` (a GNU extension as well), not `-vl` which report the files that contain at least one line that doesn't match.

That should limit the number of `grep` invocations to a minimum, and for a large number of files could leverage up to three processors concurrently.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `xargs` so I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when I try your command I get `xargs: illegal option -- r` and `xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]]`

Comment: @mosvy, it would mean loading files entirely in memory (which you can only do with `-z` if the files don't contain NUL bytes). Also note that `-P` is not always enabled and is still considered _experimental_ in GNU `grep`.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, your `xargs` doesn't appear  to be GNU `xargs`. You can drop `-r` as it's only there to prevent running commands for empty inputs. But from the usage, it looks like it doesn't support `-0` either so it can probably not be used reliably. What system are you on?

Comment: @mosvy, no I meant that for `grep -Pr` to be able to report files that contain *as a whole* DSL, 2019 and not FAILED (using lookaround operators), you'd need to use `-z` and assume the files don't contain NUL characters.

Comment: ok right, got it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Solaris 10 1/13

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, `xargs` is not usable reliably on Solaris, you may want to install the GNU tools there. If you have a `grep` that supports `-r` and `-L`, you probably have some GNU tools already. Maybe GNU `xargs` is available as `gxargs`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It's a company VM, I can't install anything. I'll have to use what's available.